# How could Dumbledore live longer than normal humans without negative effects?

Tags: harry-potter

Dumbledore was a human and by increasing his life span, he was defying nature like Voldemort. Why wasn't there any curse or negative effects from that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Harry Potter, how old will a wizard live to be on average?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11829/in-harry-potter-how-old-will-a-wizard-live-to-be-on-average)

Comment: Please, explain close votes..

Comment: I feel like it is not significantly different from the question I refereneced. On the other hand I noticed that the one didn't pull up the other for the search, so maybe it is okay.

Comment: @JackBNimble This one seems to be less "What is the average age," and more "Why." I don't think they're dupes.

Comment: @GabeWillard Any search for this question's answer will turn up that one, because it specifically asks about Dumbledore in the question body.  Likewise, ykombinator's answer in that one can be copied verbatim into this one and be the best answer.  I'd certainly call it a duplicate.

Comment: @Izkata Do you have mind? Seriously? Don't change the definition of duplicate. That question is asking for mathematical figure, but this one isn't. Plus, ykombinator's answer isn't answer of this question at all. That answer starts saying that lifespan isn't that different. Do you think, Dumbledore's lifespan was natural. The big thing: This question isn't about that thing.. Its about negative effect of dark art. Also, don't ignore Voldemort in question..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Read it again.  From ykombinator's answer, here's the answer to this question:  `Wizards do have a longer life expectancy than their Muggle counterparts for reasons explained below`.  If you believe Dumbledore used something like unicorn blood or horcruxes to extend his own life, state that in the question, _then_ ask why he didn't suffer any ill effects. (Preferably with a quote, because AFAIK, there was never anything of the sort in the books or movies)

Comment: @Izkata That doesn't make this question duplicate. Discussion is meaningless...

Comment: Wait, do we know whether Dumbledore has ever consumed the Elixir (from the Philosopher's Stone) at all?

Comment: You are implying that there *should* be negative effects to Dumbledore's (or anyone's) prolonged lifespan; when it has clearly been established that a prolonged lifespan is *normal* (or at least doesn't bring about negative or dark  consequences - inherently). Funny how the accepted answer here is pretty much the same answer on the other Q.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One major reason members of the Wizarding world live longer than normal humans is very simple: they have **much** better medicine than we do. We see Madam Pomfrey completely regrow Harry's arm bones from nothing, at one point, and she's a *school nurse*. I imagine the things that commonly lead to death of old age in humans (cancers, heart disease, neurological conditions) really pose no difficulty to magical medicine, especially at someplace like St. Mungo's.

As an aside, this can be seen in **our world**, too. If you look at the life expectancy of the Dark Ages (around mid 30's on average), *we* have made much progress towards a Wizarding lifespan. The medical community has been postulating for the past decade that if we could overcome a few of the more troubling diseases we commonly face, then *we* could live lives well over a hundred years long.

Comment: Old answer, but I felt like commenting: Madam Pomfrey may be just a *school nurse*, but she is the school nurse at *Hogwarts*. Faculty and Staff at Hogwarts seem to be (with a few plot-driven exceptions like Lockhart and Trelawney) the best in the wizarding world at what they do. You have Dumbledore, Flitwick, McGonagall, Snape, pseudo-Moody, Hagrid, etc. All very talented in their fields and very capable in practical applications of their magic ability and knowledge (if you're wondering why I included Hagrid; he has an amazing affinity with magical beasts). Pomfrey should be no different.

Comment: Even though old question and answer, I cannot stop myself from adding a little comment due to a common misconception about the very short life expectancy during the Dark Ages. In fact the average age of adults easily went up to 50/60 and more. Issues of the low average arise from a high death rate of new-borns and children.

Answer (score 15):

Dumbledore's lifespan isn't unnatural *for a wizard*. Other wizards who have naturally lived to a similar age to him or older include:

- Grindelwald was his childhood friend and doesn't die until *Deathly Hallows* when Voldemort kills him.
- Griselda Marchbanks was his N.E.W.T. examiner -- so she's presumably significantly older than him -- and she still serves on the Wizengamot and does N.E.W.T. exams as of *Order of the Phoenix*.

Presumably wizards simply live longer than Muggles.

Comment: You have just increased the question's domain... Nothing more.

Comment: @SachinShekhar If you're implying that Micah didn't answer the question then I disagree.  You're the one making the assumption that wizards and muggles have the same life span.  It would appear that this is an incorrect assumption so they aren't "defying nature" like you imply.

Comment: @Dason Do you have canonical reference of that? Or, give me example of an old magic user who isn't skilled..

Comment: @Dason I see what Sachin Shekhar is saying: there aren't many examples of witches or wizards living as long or longer than Dumbledore does that aren't also very skilled/powerful, so it seems to lead more toward his interpretation that these wizards are living longer due to something they proactively do/are, and not simply innately longer lives because they are wizards.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: Aberforth Dumbledore is not particularly skilled, and is only three years younger than his brother. For that matter, I'm not sure how much evidence there is of Marchbanks being *magically* skilled (as opposed to politically savvy/well-connected).

Comment: @Micah He wasn't skilled? He repelled thousands of Dementors. How? Mind it, only great wizard could do that...

Comment: There is also Ron's aunt who's like 107 and Bathilda too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it helps when you are friends with Nicolas Flamel ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Stan how isn't it an answer? It is short, but answers the question...

Comment: @nicael - because there's about ZERO canon information that being friends with Flamel in any way helped extend Dumbledore's life. 100% canon points to the fact that Elixir was only taken by Flamel and his wife.

Comment: well, there is ZERO canon information about from where the food in Hogwarts comes too, but people haven't given up SPECULATING, have they? And if u had a friend with Elixir of life, won't you request for some?

Answer (score -1):

wizards has better medicine, if a wizard avoid magical illness, he should be okay, in the books, hardly any wizard suffered from magical diseases unless it was caused by a spell (or human accidents), and most diseases that we suffer can be healed by magic i presume,

Comment: Welcome to the site. In the future, when you answer an old question it is preferable that you add new information.

Comment: i guess you ignored the in the <<books, hardly any wizard suffered from magical diseases unless it was caused by a spell (or human accidents)>>  part, i didn't see anybody  talk about that so it's new

I'm sure if wizards found a way to teleport and read minds or regrow skeleton or create perfect camouflage cloaks, i'm sure we can cure AIDS when  we get to a stage where our technology includes all that I've mentioned

Comment: pardon my grammatical errors :)