# How long can wizards live?

Tags: harry-potter

I was reading https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/time-turner because of another question on here, and I have read:

> Her body had aged five centuries in its return to the present and, irreparably damaged

Which means that wizards can live over five centuries? Is there any more information on this?

Comment: possibly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11829/in-harry-potter-how-old-will-a-wizard-live-to-be-on-average?rq=1

also Nicholas Flamel could theoretically live indefinitely thanks to Philosopher's Stone.

Comment: The answers on the duplicate cover both *average* life expectancy and extreme lifespan.

Comment: Please make an answer with the essential parts, and link to that. It does have the answers I want, and I want whoever found it to get some credit(a.k.a reputation)

Comment: That's not how we do things here, unfortunately. I found the link, but I don't want any reputation for it, thanks anyway though ;)

Answer (score -2):

I believe they normally live as much as *healthy* normal people (Muggles). Keep in mind that they do not have diseases because most of them can be magically cured, so they mainly die because of old age - making the life expectancy higher than the average for Muggles.

There are some tricks for them though to live longer like e.g. Philosopher's Stone (in Harry Potter 1), *horcruxes* (like Voldemort did and would allow him to leave forever - as long as they existed) or possibly other filters.

Comment: But we know that wizards [live to be much older than Muggles](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-scholastic-chat.htm)