# How old was Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

In the Harry Potter movies, Ron, Harry and Hermione joke about how old Dumbledore is, but end up laughing.
I wondered how old he was, since he 'invited' tom riddle to Hogwarts....etc.

Comment: According to [the wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Albus_Dumbledore) he was 115 years old when he died. Seems like you could have found that out yourself with next to do effort if you'd just done a quick search.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Wikia isn't a wildly known resource - nor is it really authoritative. Especially HP Wikia which is full of holes and made up things.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: DVK is right. Wikia says Harry's a Horcrux whilst actually he is not.

Comment: @DVK The Wikia page is the second entry (for me) when I do a Google search for "How old is Albus Dumbledore?" and, regardless of the Wikia's reliability in general, in this case is reliably sourced from statements in the books and JKR's personal website (the same link you used in your answer, funnily enough).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/wotm.cfm (Wizard of the Month page on JKR's official web site) had Dumbledore as WOTM for September 2007 (archived at [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20070815000000*/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/wotm.cfm))

The page said:

> Albus Dumbledore: **1881 - 1996** ...

... meaning he was 115 when he died as per JKR's latest official data (as opposed to 150 as previously speculated).

But, as [@slytherincess noted in previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11814/976), JKR is notoriously bad at math so take it with a huge grain of salt.