# Was Dumbledore an animagus?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

We know that Sirius Black, James Potter, McGonagall, and Pettigrew are animagi. Is Dumbledore an animagus or are there any other animagus characters mentioned in the Harry Potter series?

Comment: I don't think there's any mention that Dumbledore is. However Mcgonagall, Pettigrew and Rita Skeeter are

Comment: Just curious, do you have a reason to suspect that he may be an animagus?

Comment: In PoA Hermione mentions that there had only been a few animagi hence why she knew that Pettigrew couldn't be an animagi. http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Animagus

Comment: **Pettigrew could not be a registered Animagi

Comment: @Voldemort He guesses an awful lot of things that he seems to have no way to know, and an animal form unknown to everyone would be an ideal way to spy.  Further, he states in *Stone* that he has ways of becoming invisible without a cloak.

Comment: @b_jonas, though, to be fair, so does Moody and by extension every wizard who passed the circulum: the dissilusionment spell or however it's spelled.

Comment: @b_jonas - he and Grindewald used disillusionment charm.

Comment: Can any 15k user please protect the question?  It's getting a lot of spam.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dumbledore actually helped McGonagall becoming an animagus when she was his student, according to JKR on Pottermore. This might suggest that he himself was an animagus.

However, there is no canon evidence to support this theory. Additionally Dumbledore would have no reason (in my opinion) to keep this a secret. So if he was one, it would most likely be known to the ministry (and thus to us).

Comment: Just to add:  

Dumbledore was the Transfiguration teacher before McGonagall and the most accomplished wizard of his time.

Hermione's research showed Animagi registered in the twentieth century; at 150 years old, if Dumbledore became an Animagus during school (beginning in 1892) or shortly thereafter, he wouldn't be on the list.

Just hard to believe he wouldn't be, although there's no direct proof that he was.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11813/4918 "What age did Dumbledore live to?" which explains that some of us now believe the 150 years old is wrong, and Dumbledore was born in 1881.  That still leaves a time window for him to have become an Animagus in the previous century.

Comment: Just because Dumbledore knew the theory on how to become an animagus, could teach it to McGonagall, and walk her through the process, doesn't mean he used the theory on himself. There are many great coaches who are terrible players. (Likewise, many great players who are terrible coaches.)

Comment: "So if he was one, it would most likely be known to the ministry (and thus to us)." We actually don't know who's on the Ministry's list; Hermione only told us that the Marauders and Rita Skeeter were not. She might have seen Dumbledore's name on the list and simply not mentioned it, finding it unsurprising and irrelevant to the conversation.

Answer (score 6):

Not very likely.

All animagi in canon<sup>1</sup> are clearly identified:

- Minerva McGonagall: cat, registered
- James Potter: stag, unregistered
- Sirius Black: dog, unregistered
- Peter Pettigrew: rat, unregistered
- Rita Skeeter: bug, unregistered.

(Note that Remus Lupin was a werewolf, not an animagus).

---

Of course, *anyone* could be or have been an animagus and just not have used the ability, but there is no reason to believe there are any unidentified animagi<sup>2</sup>.

While Dumbledore was a transfiguration teacher prior to becoming headmaster and tutored McGonagall, there is simply no evidence of him having become one.

<sup>1: In fan fiction, anyone can turn out to be an animagus, often to comply with rule 34.</sup>
<sup>2: Hermione once grew some whiskers, but that was because of a polyjuice mishap. And Draco turned into a ferret once, but not through his own volition.</sup>

Comment: Dumbledore was a transfiguration teacher for many years so it is possible that he would know how. However Mcgonagall was always said to be the best in her field.

Comment: According to http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Animagus there are actually very few registered animagus in the cannon. The section 'Known Animagus' on the linked page shows only two registered and of those one was of so little consequence that they weren't even named.

Comment: There were only 7 registered in the twentieth century which means that even if the four unregistered that we know about are the only four it is still something that most who do it seem to want to keep hidden.

Comment: @krowe Werewolves don't count as animagi, so 3 unregistered, not 4

Comment: @CyanAngel Rita is the fourth!

Comment: @LarsEbert Do'h, of course she is, I developed a mental block for that character I think lol