# What kind of magic stops when its creator dies, which doesn't?

Tags: harry-potter

Through the book series there have been examples of charms stopping when its creator dies (Harry could move again after Dumbledore fell in HBP), but also of charms continue working (Protection of Privet Drive in DH, protection of Grimmauld place against Snape by Moody).

Is there further information what kind of magic is influenced by the death of its creator and which isn't?

Comment: In general - such as charms vs. enchantments type of thing?

Comment: related, possible dupe: [Is a spell forever?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49212/5184)

Comment: @phantom42 that seems indeed to cover my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem like at least some jinxes don't last after its creator's death.

Browing from [@CandiedMango's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60148):

In an [interview](http://www.beyondhogwarts.com/harry-potter/articles/jk-rowling-goes-beyond-the-epilogue.html) JKR said that

> J.K. said that "McGonagall was really getting on a bit," and nineteen years after the Battle of Hogwarts, there is an entirely new headmaster. Also, there is a new Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher, and that position is now as safe as the other teaching posts at Hogwarts, since **Voldemort's death broke the jinx** that kept a Defense Against the Dark Arts professor from remaining for more than a year

*emphasis mine

Comment: Not to mention Dumbledore's full body bind on Harry ended as soon as he died.