# Do wizards live longer than most Muggles?

Tags: harry-potter

Professor McGonagall was already getting on with years the the Original HP series.

From a person who has not read Cursed Child yet, I'm only reading it from here

[answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60148/57642)

And she's able to live for 19 years, without retiring...

And also Dumbledore is older than dirt,

[Dumbledore was 150 years old](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11814/57642)

With Elphias Doge, and Professor something, who supposedly tested Dumbledore on the OWL's (I think, correct me if I'm wrong).

And JKR can simply not be that bad at math(s).