# What justifies the age of Albus Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, age

I was wondering about Dumbledore's age. What justifies that he's so old, as described in the books and websites. My first guess was that he owns one of the Hallows, but then, how could Abelforth be that old ans alive too?

Then I came across this question [What age did Dumbledore live to?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11813/what-age-did-dumbledore-live-to) and notably the first answer, stating that JK Rowling says that "Wizards have a much longer life expectancy than Muggles. (Harry hasn't found out about that yet.)". This would render Dumbledore longevity not that impressive at all...

Do we have any more information about Wizards life-span? And how come that every pure blood kid seems unaware of that too?

Comment: Is it ever commented that his age is anything special or impressive?

Comment: I don't have the books with me to do a précise quote but it is stated that he is really old (maybe it's Ron Weasley who says that). So that makes it special. Moreover, being 115 years old at the end of The Half-Blood Prince, so around 107 in the first book, and far from retirement, is, in my opinion, impressive

Comment: To a bunch of 11 year old kids, **30** is "really old".

Comment: @Chronocidal  Yes, but 11 year old kids are also capable of reading things which give them impressions about normal human longevity.  For example, they ought to be able to read the dates of birth and death of their ancestors and note their ages at death.  They might note the ages of death of various historical persons they read about. 
 They would notice the dates when their elderly  relatives died, and might learn the birth years of those elderly relatives.  They can read about human longevity in various sources.  And pure blood kids could learn about both muggle and wizard longevity.